# How long has he working here?

Tags: sentence-construction

If you want to ask someone how long he has been working here can we say "he is working since how long? I heard this sentence somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You basically say the correct answer in your post:

> If you want to ask someone **how long he has been working here**

In English, this type of question is formed by switching the subject (he) and auxiliary verb (has). The correct formation of the question would be "How long **has he** been working here?" [You can read more about this here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb#Diagnostics_for_identifying_auxiliary_verbs_in_English)